# Euclidean Topology

Tags: general-topology

Find a counter example to show that the identity function Id: (R,Tc) -> (R,Te), x -> x is not continuous.

where R is the reals, Tc is the co countable topology on R and Te is the euclidean topology on R.

Comment: Is $\text{Id}^{-1}\bigl((0,1)\bigr)$ open?

Answer (score 2):

If $id\colon (\mathbb{R}, T_c) \to (\mathbb{R}, T_e)$ were continuous, then the inverse image of the open set $(0,1)$, namely $(0,1)$, would be open in $T_c$, i.e. it would be co-countable; but it isn't.